# What is a pump reflector?

Tags: optics, semiconductor-physics, laser, optical-materials

I understand the meaning of laser pumping. But i don't understand what is a pump reflector. As a clear definition does  not appear online.

In the paper,DESIGN AND DEVELOPMENT OF WIDEBAND HYBRID RAMAN/EDFA FIBER AMPLIFIER of MUDHAFAR HUSSEIN ALI, SHFA 's pumping efficiency is increased because of the adoption of pump reflectors.

excerp1)SHFA with wide gain bandwidth of 65 nm from 1530 nm to 1595 nm and lower gain variation of 0.2 dB. In this design, the pumping efficiency is increased because the signal and pump double–pass the gain medium and adopt pump reflectors.

exerp2)After that, PHFA utilizing power equalization technique was proposed by [41] in order to reduce the gain variation from 9.8 dB to less than ± 0.5 dB. The authors also used the concept of sharing single pump power by optimally dividing with pump ratio of 1:10. In addition, two pump reflectors are introduced to increase the pumping efficiency. The previous works mentioned above, the input signal was split according to wavelength bands (C and L).

Is thee a difference with the laser pump ?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a reflector that reflects the pump beam? If it reflected the pump beam back through the gain medium, it could effectively increase the pump power and thus the laser efficiency.

Comment: If you think it could be something else, can you include an exerpt from the paper where you read it, showing how it's used in context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From above, "In this design, the pumping efficiency is increased because the signal and pump double–pass the gain medium and adopt pump reflectors."

In the context of laser design, a pump reflector is a device that sends the remaining pump energy that emerges from the gain medium back through the gain medium for a second, third, etc, time to increase efficiency.  This is what they are doing here, which in fiber-based systems is particularly simple since you can usually use a fiber Bragg reflector.